# How to calculate the standard deviation to be used for a confidence interval on a weighted data set?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, weighted-data, survey-weights

Although there were some similar questions on the board, none seemed to quite be the same as what I'm asking.

I have a set of survey values (satisfaction ratings) that have been weighted for non-response and I want to construct a confidence interval around that weighted set.

The weights were created based on non-response of certain population members. I believe the procedure I used is known as "post-stratification" weights. I divided the population into 14 strata, where each stratum represented a unique combination of various levels of two factors (age and product owned) and the proportion of the population that belongs to each stratum was known. Then, to assign a weight to each observation within a particular stratum, the proportion of the population in that stratum  was divided by the proportion of the sample in that stratum.

Here's the problem: When I calculate the standard deviation of the weighted values, it is 4.16, whereas the standard deviation for the unweighted values is 2.12. This is causing the confidence interval to be about twice as wide. I understand that the weighting procedure can introduce some instability in the metrics, but I'm uncertain if there is another way I should be calculating standard deviation given that I have weighted the data?

Comment: I believe I found an explanation here: "In a stratified sample, the best estimate of the population variance is not given by this formula,
which would correspond to the standard deviation of one stratum. What is needed is the weighted average of the standard deviations of the various strata, computed relative to each stratum mean, instead of the overall mean.

Comment: Assuming each stratum represents a proportion fk of the
population, and a proportion gk of the sample, the estimate of the population standard deviation is the weighted average of the standard deviation observed in the various strata, weighted by their
share in the population (fk).

Comment: It is not particularly surprising that your standard errors have gone up. It simply means that your sample was out of balance compared to the population. Both of these (imbalance and increase in standard errors) happen quite often in the practice of survey statistics.